# Superfish Menu links disappear on iOS (only if they have dropdown menus)

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I've got a superfish menu as the main menu on my site. Two of the links in the menu have sub-links and are presented as a drop-down, hover menu. This works great on desktop browsers. On iOS, however, the main link disappears if that menu item has a drop down. It's only gone in the default state though, if I tap on the spot where it should be, the link shows up again and the drop-down menu appears as it should. If I tap the other link which has a drop down menu, the first drop down will disappear and so will the main link. For example, if the normal menu looks like this..

`FOO` `BAR` `BAZ` `BAT`

and BAR has a drop down menu, then the menu will look like this on iOS:

`FOO` `<empty space>` `BAZ` `BAT`

but if I tap on that empty space, then `BAR` will show up and so will the drop-down menu.

I've checked the CSS and don't see any differences in the styles.

I'm sorry I can't give you a link to the site to see where this is happening. I'm under an NDA and the site isn't public yet.

**EDIT**: I discovered that the css sets `.sf-menu li` to have `position: relative`. When I disable this rule in the inspector, then `BAR` appears in the spot where it should be. However, when I do this, the drop-down menus no longer have the correct context for their positioning. So, I need this rule so the drop-downs work properly, but something about that rule is causing those elements to jump out of position.

So, two questions:

1) Do you know why this is happening and do you know of a fix?

2) or, do you know of a way to make them non-drop downs when iOS is detected? The dropdowns are not crucial to my site navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enough tinkering and I found a solution. I'm not sure WHY it works, but it does.

During my experiments, I wondered if the z-index was the problem and if it was getting covered by something, so I cranked the z-index up to 10000 but that still didn't solve it.

I eventually discovered the `position: relative` thing I mentioned above. So I opened up the Computed Style box and toggled the `position: relative` rule on and off, on and off, which would break it, fix it, break it, fix it. Then I looked in the Computed values to see if anything else changed. Sure enough, the z-index changed. When it was in the working state the computed z-index was `auto`, so I created a css rule to explicitly set z-index to auto for those elements and viola... it's working.

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else.

Comment: z-index can be a tricky little so-and-so, the only way to apply the rules to a particular scenario is to know everything about how it reacts to static/relative/fixed positioned elements in relation to the current stacking order. If you've got the time (and energy!) I'd recommend [this tuotrial](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/), it demystifies the whole thing pretty well